# Two image files created with this code, one of which is .png which contains the actual file and another file with actual name which is of 0kb

Tags: php, android

```
<?php

 $sql ="SELECT id FROM yoring ORDER BY id ASC";

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $designation=$_POST['designation'];
    $company=$_POST['company'];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
    $workno=$_POST['workno'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $association=$_POST['association'];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $code=$_POST['code'];
        $id = 0;
        $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
       $id = $row['id'];
        }

        $image = $_POST['image'];



        $path = "uploads/$id.png";


        $actualpath = "http://sumitmehra.esy.es/$path";

    $insertquery = mysqli_prepare($con , "INSERT INTO yoring ( name ,designation , company, email, mobile, workno, address, association, password,username,code,pic) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insertquery , "ssssiissssis", $name, $designation , $company, $email  ,$mobile, $workno, $address, $association, $password,$username,$code,$actualpath);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($insertquery);

        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
    mysqli_stmt_close($insertquery);
    mysqli_close($con);



?>
```

Screenshot of file directory on server where file is created:

[image: Screenshot of file directory on server where file is created]

Two image files created with this code, one of which is .png which contains the actual file and another file with actual name which is of 0kb plz help me

Comment: Where is "this" code?

Comment: What's the question and where is the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overwritten id from database. Put your query $res after $id = 0.

Comment: Give me your HTML.

Comment: thank u for ur response.i tried your suggestion.now it creates 2 files i file directory with 0.png whichi is empty and second file 1.png which contains actual image. but in my database it stores http://sumitmehra.esy.es/uploads/0.png which is actually null

Comment: i am doing in android